# Kinect toolbox detecting new shapes

Tags: kinect, kinect.toolbox

**Problem**

So i am using kinect toolbox (source:http://kinecttoolbox.codeplex.com/)  and want to detect other shapes than circle. But i can't find a way how to make a 'CircleKB.save' type file (which is used by this toolbox) for any other shape as i don't know what is in this circle knowledge base file or how it is made. 
or simply tell me a how i can add custom gestures in this toolbox.

Answer (score 0):

You should edit your "Learningmachine.cs" like this:

```
public void AddPath(RecordedPath path)
{
    path.CloseAndPrepare();
    Paths.Add(path);
    SaveTheGestureInFile();
}

public void SaveTheGestureInFile()
{
    using (Stream recordStream = File.Create(@"D:\Research\Kinect Toolbox\Sources\GesturesViewer\Data\abc.save")) //wherever you want to save the file.
    {
        Persist(recordStream);
    }
}
```